# query SQL table for the same data in column for 3 times in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

```
Id, Response
1, Yes
2, Yes
3, No
4, No
5, Yes
6, No
7, No
8, No
```

I would like to be able to query the table and check for the response of No and if it occurs  3 times in a row return a value.

So I am trying

```
select count(response) where response = no
order by id
```

Basically, the theory goes, if there are 3 responses of No, I want to trigger something else to happen. So I need to query the table each time an entry is made, and if the last 3 entries are no then return value.
I only want to know if the latest values are 3 no.  for example if the last 4 entries were no, no, no, yes - I don't care as there is a yes value
so the last 3 values have to be no

Comment: Think Windows Functions is the way to go, but can you please provide correct demo data? Your Information is nearly unreadable

Comment: What do you mean by "3 times in a row". Do you mean, the column ID should follow some kind of sequence or do we simply follow the heap order ? What do you expect if there is a hole in those IDs (example : I delete row that has Id 5) ?

Comment: @braddo . .. Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which RDBMS you use, but you can try something like that:

```
select count(*)
  from
(select id,
        response
   from your_table
  order by id desc
  limit 3) t
 where t.response = 'No';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in Bigquery. You may need to tweak the syntax for you SQL base:

```
SELECT 
* , 
SUM( CASE WHEN response ="No" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
             OVER (ORDER BY id RANGE BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
FROM dataset
```

It returns output like this:

[image]

Which I think is what you want.
The key part is the window functions using  `RANGE BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`. The case statement is checking if the current row and the 2 before are "No". If they are return a 1. So when three in a row occur this will SUM to 3.

Comment: thats cool
so that tells me that the 8th record is 3 consecutive No responses.
so now i need to check for that, and if the value is 3 then perform another action
how would this be accomplished

Comment: So something like this will "check" for it and then the rows will be ready for whatever action you want to apply:
```WITH data_prep AS (
SELECT 
* , 
SUM( CASE WHEN response ="No" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
             OVER (ORDER BY id RANGE BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)  as check
FROM dataset
)
SELECT  *
FROM data_prep 
WHERE check = 3 
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with window functions and a derived table or CTE term.  The following takes you through how it can be done, step by step:

[Full Example with data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=185966ebf5e23a22bea56c8758ed4ebb)

```
WITH cte1 AS (
        SELECT x.*
             , CASE WHEN COALESCE(LAG(response) OVER (ORDER BY id), 'NA') <> response THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS edge
          FROM xlogs AS x
     )        
   , cte2 AS (
        SELECT x.*
             , SUM(edge) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS xgroup
          FROM cte1 AS x
     )        
   , cte3 AS (
        SELECT x.*
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY xgroup ORDER BY id) AS xposition
          FROM cte2 AS x
     )        
   , cte4 AS (
        SELECT x.*
             , CASE WHEN xposition >= 3 AND response = 'No' THEN 1 END AS xtrigger
          FROM cte3 AS x
     )        
   , cte5 AS (
        SELECT x.*
          FROM cte4 AS x
         ORDER BY id DESC
         LIMIT 1
     )        
SELECT *
  FROM cte5
 WHERE response = 'No'
;
```

The result of cte4 provides useful detail about the logic:

```
+----+----------+------+--------+-----------+----------+
| id | response | edge | xgroup | xposition | xtrigger |
+----+----------+------+--------+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Yes      |    1 |      1 |         1 |     NULL |
|  2 | Yes      |    0 |      1 |         2 |     NULL |
|  3 | No       |    1 |      2 |         1 |     NULL |
|  4 | No       |    0 |      2 |         2 |     NULL |
|  5 | Yes      |    1 |      3 |         1 |     NULL |
|  6 | No       |    1 |      4 |         1 |     NULL |
|  7 | No       |    0 |      4 |         2 |     NULL |
|  8 | No       |    0 |      4 |         3 |        1 |
+----+----------+------+--------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: It can be collapsed.  But this might be informative.

Comment: thanks for that.. i think the xposition return will help.
as what i need to do is run the query, and if the value is 3, then i perform a task
so i need to run the query, and then if value is 3 - do something else

Answer (score 0):

I would use two `lag()`s:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(id, 2) over (order by id) as prev2_id,
             lag(id, 2) over (order by id) as prev2_id_response
      from t
     ) t
where response = 'no' and prev2_id = prev2_id_response;
```

The first `lag()` determines the id "2 back".  The second determines the id "2 back" for the same response.  If the response is the same for those three rows, then these are the same.

This returns each occurrence of "no" where this occurs.  You can use `exists` if you just want to know if this ever occurs.